# Proving fundamental theorem of calculus by computing Riemann integral of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, proof-writing

Inspired by the answer:

https://mathoverflow.net/a/130905/122587

on an old mathoverflow question, I recently thought a lot about the fundamental theorem of calculus. If $F : [a,b] \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous, differentiable on $(a,b)$ with Riemann integrable $F'$, then
$$
\int_a^x F'(t)\, dt = F(x) - F(a).
$$
Is there a proof that begins with the left-hand side and computes the Riemann integral of the function $F'$?

The most common proof explicitly uses the Mean Value Theorem to turn $F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1})$ into $F'(c)(x_j - x_{j-1})$ and therefore goes from a sum of increments into a Riemann sum for $F'$ If we start on the left we are presented upfront with a Riemann sum for $F'$. In general there is no converse to MVT (other hypotheses are needed if I recall correctly), so what can we do to compute it?

Comment: Each term of the Riemann sum $F'(\xi_k) (x_k-x_{k-1})$ does remind us of the mean value theorem $f'(c) (b-a) =f(b) - f(a) $ and hence we don't expect the term to be significantly different from $F(x_k) - F(x_{k-1})$.

Comment: Using infinitesimal intuition we have $F'(x) dx=dF(x) $ and $\int_{a} ^{b} dF(x) =F(b) - F(a) $. So mean value theorem is essential in a way.